# How to add a zero in front of an integer value

Tags: java, time, number-formatting, leading-zero

I'm trying to calculate the future time when a user inputs hours and minutes separated by a space. 
I'm stuck on when the user inputs minutes that calculates the future minutes to be less than 10.

For example, if the current time now is 10:04 and the user inputs 1 hour, 4 minutes, the future time SHOULD be 11:08.

Instead, I get printed 11:8

```
int extraHours = minutesGiven/60;
hoursGiven = hoursGiven+extraHours;
// System.out.println("hoursGiven= " + hoursGiven);
int extraMinutes = minutesGiven%60;

if((minutesNow + extraMinutes)>59){
    minutesNow = minutesNow + extraMinutes-60;
}else if((minutesNow+hoursGiven)<10){
    minutesNow = minutesNow + extraMinutes;
    String padded = String.format("%02d" , minutesNow);
}else{
    minutesNow = minutesNow + extraMinutes;
}

//calculate the future hour
int futureHours = 0;
if(minutesGiven==30){
    futureHours = (hourNow + hoursGiven +1)%24;
}else{
    futureHours = (hourNow + hoursGiven)%24;
}
//print the time
System.out.println("The time will be " + futureHours + ":" + minutesNow);

// LocalTime noon = LocalTime.of(12, 0); //12 hours, 0 minutes
//System.out.println("Noon printed as a LocalTime object: " + noon);
```

Comment: As an aside, you had commented the line with `LocalTime.of(12, 0)` out. You may just use `LocalTime.NOON` to obtain the same.

Answer (score 2):

Create an if statement when you print the time like this:

```
if (minutesNow < 10)
    System.out.println("The time will be " + futureHours + ":0" + minutesNow);
else
    System.out.println("The time will be " + futureHours + ":" + minutesNow);
```

Hope it helped ;)

Comment: Phew, that was simple but effective. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use java8's LocalTime class.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter hour and minute: ");
int hour = s.nextInt();
int minute = s.nextInt();

LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
time = time.plusHours(hour).plusMinutes(minute);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm");
System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + formatter.format(time));
s.close();
```

Comment: Very good suggestion. You don’t need a formatter at all, `LocalTime.toString()` will produce the desired format. If you do use a formatter, use uppercase `HH` in the format pattern string for hours on a 24 hours clock (lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM, from 1 through 12).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 0 to the integer like this

```
String time = String.ValueOf(hours) +":"+ "0"+String.ValueOf(minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with `Date` and `Calendar` objects. They will automatically include padding for you and respect any possible daylight savings adjustments:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int minutesNow = 4;
        int hourNow = 10;
        int minutesGiven = 4;
        int hoursGiven = 1;
        try {
            String myTime = hourNow + ":" + minutesNow;
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date d = df.parse(myTime);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(d);
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesGiven);
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, hoursGiven);
            String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
            System.out.println("The time will be " + newTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While using a library class is a good idea, please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).